# Faulty (Future) /tf Time in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-gazebo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A possible bug in tf or gazebo:
I'm using the default pr2 gazebo simulator, and simulating base and tilting laser as well as the cameras.

When I look at the tf more closely, the time associated with this link is in the future by about a half second:
/base_link --> /base_laser_link

... when compared to /clock itself and other tf links (e.g. to the tilting laser or the cameras)

Has anyone noticed tf publishing a link labelled in the future - specifically in gazebo simulation?

ROS Electric | Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40799/faulty-(future)-/tf-time-in-gazebo?/) by [mfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/2993/mfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf tree of the robot is not published by gazebo directly but by the [robot_state_publisher](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) node. Have a look at its wiki page. It explicitly states that all static transforms are future dated by 0.5 seconds. See [here](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/FAQ#Do_transforms_expire.3F) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35908/using-tf-to-transform-a-point/?answer=35981#post-id-35981) for an explanation of the reasons for future-dating transforms.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1